# Simplify anonymous function in higer order functions

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

Assuming I have the following types:

```
data Test = Test1 | Test2
            deriving (Eq, Show)

data TestDS = TestDS {
      testField1 :: String,
      testField2 :: Test
    } deriving (Eq, Show)

testFilter :: [TestDS] -> [TestDS]
testFilter tdata = filter (\x -> testField2 x == Test2) tdata
```

Is it possible to convert the above filter function to the following form:

```
filter (Test2 == testField2) tdata
```

(The above filter function of course produces a compile error)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
filter ((Test2 ==) . testField2) tdata
```

Remember that (Test2 ==) and testField2 are both functions that can be composed.

Answer (score 7):

```
filter (\x -> testField2 x == Test2) tdata
```

It seems you put parentheses incorrectly in your mind. The code is not

```
filter ((\x -> testField2 x) == Test2) tdata
```

It is really

```
filter (\x -> (testField2 x == Test2)) tdata
```

So eta-reduction rule ("`\x -> foo x` can be replaced with `foo`") is not applicable.

To have it applicable you need to move x to the end of lambda body. Firstly we use commutativity of `==`:

```
filter (\x -> (Test2  == (testField2 x))) tdata
```

I put extra parentheses to clarify that eta-reduction is still not applicable. Now the idea is to apply function composition rule ("`foo (bar x)` can be replaced with `foo . bar`"), but to demonstrate what are `foo` and `bar` in our example I will use prefix form of `==`:

```
filter (\x -> ((==) Test2 (testField2 x))) tdata
```

Now it's clear that `foo` is `(==) Test2` and `bar` is `textField2`:

```
filter ((==) Test2 . testField2)) tdata
```

Now instead of `(==) Test2` we can use so called operator section. `(== foo)` (parentheses are mandatory) is the same as `\x -> x == foo`. (foo ==) is the same as `'x -> foo == x`.

```
filter ((== Test2) . testField2)) tdata
```

or

```
filter ((Test2 ==) . testField2)) tdata
```

Answer (score 0):

You can say

```
filter ((Test2 ==) . testField2) tdata
```

or also (my preference) use a list comprehension:

```
[ t | t@TestDS{testField2 = Test1} <- tdata ]
```